# Retrieve value from Map<String, dynamic> after getting it from an API

Tags: list, api, hashmap, dart, flutter

I'm trying to get a value from an API and usually I get it through a list and just use an index and the String to get the info I need (e.g. `data[index]["String"]`), however this API sends a `Map<String, dynamic>` and I used the key to retrieve part of the Map (`data["key"]`}) but I am trying to be more specific in the value. Is there a way to get the exact value, like `data["key"]["String"]`?

Comment: Please provide sample data and the code that shows what you tried and where you failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use json.decode on your data

Example :

```
var response = await /* httpcall */

var data = json.decode(response.body);
```

Depending on the structure of your response you might have to change the field that you json encode, but at least you can now use `data['foo']['bar']`